# Extra line breaks in output to file

Tags: php

I am trying to save the content of a textarea to a text file, but am having some trouble with extra line breaks being inserted.

As an example, let's say I enter this into the textarea:

```
dsfgsdfgdsfgdsg
line2
dsfgdfgdfg
line4
```

The PHP code that writes this to the text file is:

```
$content = $_POST['accountMappings'];
$file = "../userlist.txt";
$Saved_File = fopen($file, 'w');
fwrite($Saved_File, $content);
fclose($Saved_File);
```

The text gets written to the text file, but it gets written like this:

```
dsfgsdfgdsfgdsg

line2

dsfgdfgdfg

line4
```

There is an extra line break after each line.

There is nothing else manipulating the code before being saved by the code you see above. Where are these extra blank lines coming from?

Comment: Are you using any Rich text Editor?

Comment: No, just a plain textarea

Comment: Inspect the textarea with firebug  after inserting data , the browser by default will be adding `<br>` or `<p>` tag while you add new line.

Comment: This might be a issue of line endings. on what platform are you opening the txt file. - windows/mac/linux? As I have checked it appears to work fine on my windows system.

Comment: Firebug doesn't show data that you insert, unless the data is part of the code and loaded into the page. Data you type in manually doesn't show up when inspected with Firebug.

Comment: The server is Linux, my computer is Windows

Comment: What is the output of your $_POST['accountMappings'] ? Please post with line ending characters.

Comment: You are opening the linux system generated file in your windows system?

Comment: try this before writing it to the file: `$content = preg_replace('#\r\n?#', "\n", $content);`

Comment: When I "echo" the output it outputs in a single string, with a space after each line, like this: dsfgsdfgdsfgdsg line2 dsfgdfgdfg line3

Comment: Ashish, yes, that's correct.

Comment: Angelcool, that seems to have worked. Thanks. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this before writing it to the file:

```
$content = preg_replace('#\r\n?#', "\n", $content);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with line endings. You must use the solution provided by @angelcool.net which is `$content = preg_replace('#\r\n?#', "\n", $content);`